# c# SerialPort suddenly stops receiving data and unable to reopen

Tags: c#, serial-port, raspberry-pi3, .net-5

I have a curious problem that i cant make sense of.
Here the facts:

- .net 5 Project published as arm32 linux self contained
- Running on a Raspberry pi Compute module

in one case that we cant provoke at the moment, the serial port stops receiving data and sent data seems not to reach the target.
the described process runs 24/7 for month without error.

as a attempt to solve this we implemented a watchdog that tries to reinstanciate the SerialPort in this case. But it doesnt solve the problem. a connection to the Serial port can only be regained by restarting the process.

The serial port fir all properties looks open and alive, just with the caveat that data issnt received and sent.

i have no more idead how this problem happens and how to prevent it.

Comment: Unfortunately, according to [.NET and .NET Core release lifecycle](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core), .NET 5 is no longer supported.

Comment: @user09938 the problem is happening for a long time now, also from times where net5 was still supported. upgrading to net6/7 is not possible due to external resources.

Comment: @user09938 if there are known bugfixes that relate to the problem we have i could at least propose this as a solution with valid arguments. otherwise i dont think i am in luck, since it would require external components to be changed. without such a argument is am pretty empty handed.

Comment: Buy a serial port sniffer and find out if the data is causing issues.  Do web search for "serial port sniffer".   Check the error bits on UART to see if you have any errors.  Errors can happen at either end of the connection and cause the interface to hang.  Closing and opening the port may also allow port to start working.

Comment: _" Closing and opening the port may also allow port to start working."_ - you may need to play around with offset time between close and open, though. The OS may not free resources instantly upon close.

Comment: _"upgrading to net6/7 is not possible due to external resources."_ - You _really_ need to change that. It will keep turning around and bite your rear side. It may be tolerable for _some time_ but not forever. (Where "forever" may not be as long as one might think)

Comment: @Fildor i will look into the time offset. at the moment we dont have a offset here. About he upgrade: it sucks thats true, but without arguments there will be no change. and after about 13 years this relationship is important. i would instantly upgrade, but my hands are tied.

Comment: Make it a security hazard and it will dissolve into thin air ;D

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have .NET 5 installed any more due to its out-of-support status. You haven't provided any code, but if you're using the _SerialPort Class_, you may consider reviewing the [SerialPort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) documentation. Check if your device supports _DTR_. If so, ensure that you've set `DtrEnable=true;` Same with _RTS_. Check the documentation for your device.

Comment: If your device supports _DTR_, subscribe to [SerialPort.PinChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.pinchanged?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0).

Comment: You seem to only focus on one end of the serial link. One simple and obvious reason that a "*serial port stops receiving data*" occurs when there is no data transmitted by the other end. Have you checked if that is the case or not?